# Unable to set application theme to Theme.Material in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In visual studio 2017, I created a Xamarin 4.4.0.34 "Blank app (android)" application.

I need to set the theme of the application to `Theme.Material`. Following [this document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material_theme/), I added `the android:theme` property to the `application` element under `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material"></application>`

Setting the Material theme as no effect and I still get the default theme (image below) when I deploy to my device that runs `Android 4.4.4 (api 19)`.

I tried also to set the theme under `AssemblyInfo.cs` as well as directly on the `[Activity]` attribute, both didn't work.

On the other hand, setting the theme to `Theme.Holo.Light` under `AndroidManifest.xml` works.

**What am I missing?**
**Does `Theme.Material` need to be installed or imported somehow?**

#### Details

- Xamarin 4.4.0.34
- Xamarin Android SDK 7.2.0.7
- Compile version is Android 7.1 (Nougat)
- Minimum Version is Android 4.1(api 16)
- Target Android version is Android 7.1(Nougat)

#### Theme I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your article it says:

> Because Material Theme is supported only on Android 5.0, you cannot
>   use it (or a custom theme derived from Material Theme) to theme your
>   app for running on earlier versions of Android. However, you can
>   configure your app to use Material Theme on Android 5.0 devices and
>   gracefully fall back to an earlier theme when it runs on older
>   versions of Android (see the Compatibility section of this article for
>   details).

Your 4.4.4 device doesnt know what you mean with Theme.Material, its something from a newer Android version.

Check [this  Android Support v7 AppCompat Guide](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/) on how to correctly use Material Design themes, controls, and features on previous Android versions.